# Why does it only returns 11 of my loop as I scrape using puppeteer? Click "show more" button until reaches the end

Tags: puppeteer

I have this code:
with a url of: [block.hacash.org](http://block.hacash.org)

I am using Puppeteer on Firefox, headless, hosted on VPS.

```
function hacdName() {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll('td.t2.gray.dts');
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.innerText);
  }
  return items;
}
let items = await page.evaluate(hacdName);
console.log(items)
```

However the output will only return the first 10 (ten) `td.t2.gray.dts` and will not return the rest.

Example:

> [
> '00000000097f5ff183be...',
> '0000000019bcba6a3eae...',
> '0000000014895c593f29...',
> '00000000077088d50229...',
> '0000000001a143b70894...',
> '0000000013c9089db9cb...',
> '0000000006b7a707923c...',
> '000000001bfa7c9c68ec...',
> '00000000030593fa3c73...',
> '000000001af596b772c5...',
> '000000000394daca889b...'
> ]

How can I scrape all   `td.t2.gray.dts` to block 0 or until I consumed all `show more` button.

Another question :

Why does puppeteer on `td.tr.gray.dts` return (e.g. 000000000394daca889b...) not the whole (000000000394daca889b9f472f6ede90a9e835bc516d7f76f37718e5d827e6b2)?

Comment: It is not 10 but 11 strings in your output array. if I visit the url you've give: there are only 11 elements with this selector by default. if you need more: click on the "show more" buton first. you can launch puppeteer in headful mode (`puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })`) to see what puppeteer has in the browser.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, it's weird that a while ago I counted 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get all elements using the Puppeteer you need to have them on page first, to do this you can create a function that will click on the "Show More" button until it's visible

```
async function loadAllResources(page) {
  let moreButton;
  do {
    moreButton = await page.$('#blocks .pmore .button');
    if (moreButton) {
      await moreButton.click();
      await page.waitFor(1000); // some wait until the rows will be loaded
    }
  } while(moreButton)
}
```

and just call it before **scraping** all data `await loadAllResources(page);`

As for the question with no full text, it's because you're getting the `innerHtml`. To obtain the whole text you need to get the title from the link

```
function hacdName() {
  const extractedElements = document.querySelectorAll('td.t2.gray.dts a');
  const items = [];
  for (let element of extractedElements) {
    items.push(element.title);
  }
  return items;
}
```

Also, I will suggest you pay attention to the API and monitor the network tab when you're loading this resource, for example, fetching the data from the URL `http://block.hacash.org/api/block/list?last=170246&limit=1000` will be much easier and faster and can solve the same task faster.

Comment: Regarding the API if I set the limit to ```limit=1000``` it will return ```all json data``` on an android google chrome browser, however when I also use it to call for API on a windows google chrome ```if limit >=100``` it will not return any data at all. Was it a problem of browsers?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you're opening this URL in the Chrome browser? Did you try to send the get request using js/node or any other language?
Also, I will suggest investigating this endpoint and find maybe other params or restrictions.

Comment: if I set limit = 100 then it will return me all of the information I need  ```{"datas":[{"hash":"0000000004f035591843c550fa5432ea6dae8ec701fb80cb4e90e28c265c512c","txs":1,"time":1599535774,"height":169355,"nonce":368313987,"bits":3706342511,"rewards":{"amount":"ㄜ1:248","address":"1DYY4ZRsWnhjcwwnE3dWgtiqe2mctDS2HF","message":"HacPool"},"bitstr":3706342511},```. However if I set limit pass 100, for example 101 it will just return ```{"datas":169255,"ret":0}```

Comment: Did you try other endpoints like `http://block.hacash.org/api/transfer/logs?page=1&limit=1000`?
If it's also not working just create a loop that will send the request for getting 100 entries, something like


const LIMIT = 100;
do {
  const lastEntry = await getLastEntry();
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://block.hacash.org/api/block/list?last=${lastEntry}&limit=${LIMIT}`
  );
  const result = await response.json();
  await processResults(result);
} while (result.length === LIMIT);